# Convert expires_at filed from debug token in Facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, token

Hello I got a `JsonObject` by `debug_token` and I need to know what is `expires_at` / `issued_at` (What is the `dataType`) and how to convert it to `C#`'s `DateTime`.

Simply I need to know what `Facebook` means by `expires_at`.
Is it the time (seconds/minutes) to its death or correct time format (`DateTime`)
I am using Facebook `C#` SDK

JSON array I got is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "app_id": *********,
        "is_valid": true,
        "application": "MyApp1",
        "user_id": *********,
        "issued_at": 1367606488,
        "expires_at": 1372790488,
        "scopes": [
            "create_note",
            "manage_notifications",
            "photo_upload",
            "publish_actions",
            "publish_stream",
            "read_stream",
            "share_item",
            "status_update",
            "user_about_me",
            "user_photos",
            "video_upload"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: So C or C#? Tags conflict question.

Comment: @H2CO3 c# Qestion not c

Comment: Which API is that? I was under the impression that the Graph API at least would return ISO formatted strings for dates unless the client specifically requested something else.

Answer (score 2):

It's the time when the token gonna expire, in [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) format, as seen above:

> Unix time (also known as POSIX time or Epoch time) is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds. It is used widely in Unix-like and many other operating systems and file formats. Because it does not handle leap seconds, it is neither a linear representation of time nor a true representation of UTC. Unix time may be checked on most Unix systems by typing date +%s on the command line.

To check out there is a useful web site that convert this number into a readable date:

http://www.epochconverter.com/